# Grid concatenation of images in Python

Tags: image, opencv, python-imaging-library

I would like to know if there is a method using `OpenCV` or `PIL` to compose an image given a grid (matrix) of images. Something similar to OpenCV `hconcat()` and `vconcat()`, but which works with grids.

Comment: python? numpy? `np.block`